# How can i prevent users from adding wireless connections in windows 7 PC?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, group-policy

How can I prevent users from adding or connecting to new wireless networks, especially their mobile hotspots?
I did many searches on the internet but I can't find any registry trick or group policy setting to do this.
I'm looking for a solution that restricts my users from changing WLAN settings.

Comment: Is this in a corporate network?

Comment: Point 8 [here](https://petri.com/creating_wireless_gpo_settings) says "The client will only connect to these networks as long as it has had the Wireless GPO applied to it. " -- Doesn't that nail it?

Comment: Also ensure you have a good strong password for the wireless point and stated that employees are to keep it confidential. I assume legitimate employees can put their phone on the network. You can also provide easy guest access with no network access (just Internet). We do this at small clients.

Comment: already on my first search I found several suggestions like [this](http://www.edugeek.net/forums/windows/46788-prevent-students-changing-any-wireless-network-settings.html) one. Which have you tried?

Comment: thanks for the reply, all suggestions work with domain networks, in my case PCs are in a workgroup.

Answer (score 0):

The method for your reference:
Deploy a Blacklist/Whitelist Wireless Networks Via Group Policy under:
Computer Configuration > Policies > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Wireless Network (IEEE 802.11) Policies
For more details you can refer to :
https://www.grouppolicy.biz/2010/03/how-to-use-group-policy-to-blackwhite-list-wireless-networks-in-vista-windows-7/

Comment: Does it work for a PC in a WORKGROUP?
I can't see the `Wireless Network` in Group Policy